# CONCATENATE array

Tags: arrays, excel, concatenation

I'd like to CONCATENATE some columns and between them there has to be this. ";\"
The problem is that different rows have different numbers of columns. So for  example:

```
      A             B             C

1  Image1.jpg     Image2.jpg    Image3.jpg
2  Image1.jpg     Image2.jpg
3  Image1.jpg
```

If I CONCATENATE the three columns the third will look like this `Image1.jpg;\;\`

Is there an option to CONCATENATE the columns only if it's not empty?

Comment: Are you looking for a formula or VBA?  This would be pretty easy in VBA, but depending on the number of columns you have, this would be a complex formula.

Comment: Agreed with Chrismas007. If the number of columns in your actual data is only three, as per your example, then this is just about doable with worksheet formulas. Any more than that and it becomes quickly unfeasible, and therefore becomes a job suited to VBA.

Comment: I can have up to 10 column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the columns containing data are A,B and C.

In column D add the following formula:

```
=IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&";\"&B1))
```

In column E add the following formula to get the final result:

```
=IF(D1="",IF(C1="","",C1),IF(C1="",D1,D1&";\"&C1))
```

One shot formula:

```
=IF(IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&";\"&B1))="",IF(C1="","",C1),IF(C1="",IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&";\"&B1)),IF(A1="",IF(B1="","",B1),IF(B1="",A1,A1&";\"&B1))&";\"&C1))
```

We are handling 8 possible combinations of values being blank or not for three columns (2 to the power of 3). The above IF statements reflect that logic. I would personally write a VBA function instead of using such a lengthy formula.

Comment: Just completed my answer

Comment: Your formula is correct thank you but as you suggest i'll use VBA because i can have up to 10 column.

Comment: @peterc As a matter of courtesy, I would appreciate an upvote for the effort I put providing a working solution and reviewing the solutions provided by others.

Comment: Hello
Im sorry i new here,dont know the system yes.
I tried to do but i get this: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: @peterc Now I feel bad to have deprived somebody else of 15 pts :-(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
=IF(B1="",A1,IF(C1="",A1&";\"&B1,A1&";\"&B1&";\"&C1))
```

If you have very many columns your best bet may be to accept the surplus at the end in the first instance and, separately, trim it off.

---

Up to 10 at a time (no intervening blanks) but in two steps:

1. `=A1&";\"&B1&";\"&C1&";\"&D1&";\"&E1&";\"&F1&";\"&G1&";\"&H1&";\"&I1&";\ "&J1&";\"` in say K1 and copied down to suit, then select ColumnK, Copy, Paste Special, Values over the top.
2. `=LEFT(K1,LEN(K1)-2*(COUNTBLANK(A1:J1)+1))` in L1 and copied down to suit.

Comment: +1: Your answer seems to handle the three cases in the question. Assuming column A can never be blank and column B cannot be blank while column C is non blank. In that case, this is the simplest and most elegant answer.

Comment: The provided examples do not show a blank column A. See the assumptions I made in my previous comment for this answer to be valid. If all possible combinations are to be handled, my answer works or the more elegant VBA solution provided by Gary's Student.

Comment: What if A1 contains data, B1 does not and C1 does?

Comment: I have tried your formula and for A1="a" and B1="" and C1="c", I get "a"

Comment: Show me the complete formula that will handle ALL cases.

Comment: Show me a complete solution that works. Stop saying it is just an additional step.

Comment: So far, I do not see a simple solution provided to answer the question with no manual manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a **VBA** based solution.  Enter the following *UDF* in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function Konkatenate(rIn As Range) As String
    Dim r As Range, s As String
    For Each r In rIn
        s = r.Text
        If s <> "" Then
            Konkatenate = Konkatenate & ";\" & s
        End If
    Next r
    Konkatenate = Mid(Konkatenate, 3)
End Function
```

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=Konkatenate(A1:Z1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

[image]

Comment: @Tarik I do not like to "re-use" the name of an existing **Excel** worksheet function.